# What does "System-wide settings will be cleared" mean?

Tags: 11.10, installation, ubiquity

I'm reinstalling Ubuntu, and I see that there's this "upgrade" option that lets me reinstall Ubuntu while keeping files and software when possible, but says that "system wide settings" will be cleared. Are the config files and folders in my home folder ".something" go away with this or only things like sources.list? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested the upgrade. I have a separate primary root (`/`) and a `/home` partition. During the upgrade the primary root partition was changed to logical, and the `/home` filesystem was retained as another logical partition, while having a new `/home`.

The `/` was *reformatted* and thus the **system-wide settings** are cleared, but the old `/home` was *saved onto a new partition*. So it is possible to copy back old data to the new `/home` partition.

Before upgrading, it is always advised to create backups from the key areas of the system. Eg.:

- `/home`
- `/etc`
- `/boot`
- And if you have any other software installed e.g. Apache, then its corresponding directories (in this case `/var/www`, `/usr/lib/cgi-bin`).

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunaly, I left the installer in english (I wanted to see the message to write here) and forgot to put back in portuguese. I realized my mistake in the beginning of the installation and I had the option to go back. I did so, but i had problems. I closed the installer to run it again, but then the option wasn't available anymore. So I installed over the older system without formatting, as I usually do. But thanks for the info, anyway!